# line-by-line comparison only returns every second line

Tags: perl

so I'm trying to write a script that compares each line of one file with its corresponding line of file 2 (line 1 of file 1 with line 1 of file 2, etc), change the content of file 1 in a specific way, and then return this line. The code I compiled so far goes like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# alleles.pl
use strict; use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

open my $AL, '<', shift or die $!;
open my $HMP, '<', shift or die $!;

<$AL>; # skip header
print scalar <$HMP>; # print header

while (<$AL>, <$HMP>) {
  my @HMP_columns = split (/\t/, <$HMP>);
  my @AL_columns = split (/\t/, <$AL>);
  shift @AL_columns for 0..4;
  my @uniq_AL_columns = uniq(@AL_columns); # only keep unique values in new array
  for (my $i = 11; $i < scalar(@HMP_columns); $i++) { # for every column (starting from column 12)
    if ($HMP_columns[$i] == "1") {$HMP_columns[$i] = $uniq_AL_columns[0]}
    elsif ($HMP_columns[$i] == "2") {$HMP_columns[$i] = $uniq_AL_columns[1]}
    elsif ($HMP_columns[$i] == "3") {$HMP_columns[$i] = $uniq_AL_columns[2]}
    elsif ($HMP_columns[$i] == "4") {$HMP_columns[$i] = $uniq_AL_columns[3]}
    elsif ($HMP_columns[$i] == "5") {$HMP_columns[$i] = $uniq_AL_columns[4]}
    elsif ($HMP_columns[$i] == "6") {$HMP_columns[$i] = $uniq_AL_columns[5]}
    elsif ($HMP_columns[$i] == "7") {$HMP_columns[$i] = $uniq_AL_columns[6]}
    elsif ($HMP_columns[$i] == "8") {$HMP_columns[$i] = $uniq_AL_columns[7]}
    elsif ($HMP_columns[$i] == "9") {$HMP_columns[$i] = $uniq_AL_columns[8]}
  } 
  my $joined_HMP = join ("\t", @HMP_columns); # get back to tab separated lines
  print "$joined_HMP\n";
}
```

the formatting of the lines works the way I want it to work, however, the script only seems to work on every 2nd line of the inputs, or at least only return every 2nd line. I tried to initiate the while loop in many different ways and tried a lot of other things like initiating the arrays outside of the while loop, but nothing works. can anybody tell me where I am going wrong in the script? (by the way I know that the style is not pretty, so if any of you have some advise on how to make this script more compact, please feel free to do so! I wanna learn after all.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ignore lines fetched in `while` statement and fetch another lines in `split`.

Below please find fixed code. It does not detect situation when AL has more lines than HNP.

```
while (<$HMP>) {
  my @HMP_columns = split (/\t/, $_);
  if( not defined( $_  = <$AL>)) {
     die "HMP longer than AL";
  }
  my @AL_columns = split (/\t/, $_);
```

Comment: I have a short question to this code: how does perl know that when you use $_ for the first time (line 2), it is the line from the first file, and when you use $_ for the second time (line 6), it is the line from the second file? Or rather, where is the switch that changes the input of $_ between these steps?

Comment: `$_` is reassigned by `$_=<$AL>` inside `if(...)` condition.

Answer (score 2):

In each loop you are reading from each file twice. Once in the while condition clause and once in the while body.

Replace your while line with:

```
use IO::Handle;
while (!($HMP->eof() or $AL->eof()) {
```

This will cause the while condition to fail if either file reaches end. 
If it is possible for the files to have different lengths, you can check which one did not reach eof after the while loop.

Comment: thanks a lot! it worked perfectly! one question though, could you tell me what IO::Handle does? not sure if i quite get what you are doing there

Comment: There is no need for `IO::Handle`. You can achieve the same thing with `until (eof $HMP or eof $AL) { ... }` which IMO is much more readable.

Comment: IO::Handle is for handling input/output streams. See the docs: http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Handle.html

Comment: 'until' sucks almost like 'unless' does.

Answer (score 1):

A few quick tips:

Whenever you have lines of very similar repeated code, it's a sign there may be a more economical way to do things. For example, this code:

```
for (my $i = 11; $i < scalar(@HMP_columns); $i++) { # for every column (starting from column 12)
    if ($HMP_columns[$i] == "1") {$HMP_columns[$i] = $uniq_AL_columns[0]}
    elsif ($HMP_columns[$i] == "2") {$HMP_columns[$i] = $uniq_AL_columns[1]}
    elsif ($HMP_columns[$i] == "3") {$HMP_columns[$i] = $uniq_AL_columns[2]}
    elsif ($HMP_columns[$i] == "4") {$HMP_columns[$i] = $uniq_AL_columns[3]}
    elsif ($HMP_columns[$i] == "5") {$HMP_columns[$i] = $uniq_AL_columns[4]}
    elsif ($HMP_columns[$i] == "6") {$HMP_columns[$i] = $uniq_AL_columns[5]}
    elsif ($HMP_columns[$i] == "7") {$HMP_columns[$i] = $uniq_AL_columns[6]}
    elsif ($HMP_columns[$i] == "8") {$HMP_columns[$i] = $uniq_AL_columns[7]}
    elsif ($HMP_columns[$i] == "9") {$HMP_columns[$i] = $uniq_AL_columns[8]}
}
```

could be refactored - the new value of `$HMP_columns[$i]` is `$uniq_AL_columns[ $HMP_columns[$i-1] ]`, so the whole block could be rewritten as

```
for (my $i = 11; $i < scalar(@HMP_columns); $i++) {
    $HMP_columns[$i] = $uniq_AL_columns[$HMP_columns[$i-1]];
}
```

If you're dealing with arrays, the [splice function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) is extremely handy for doing all sorts of manipulations -- remove elements from an array, replace them with other elements, and so on. `shift @AL_columns for 0..4` can be written as `splice(@AL_columns, 0, 5);` (i.e. remove 5 elements from @AL_columns starting at element 0).

For any perl work, it really helps to write debugging statements and tests while you're developing scripts so that you can be sure that you know what is going on. Sprinkling your code liberally with statements that 'say' the values of variables while the script executes can really aid in the debugging process. Once the code goes into production use, the 'say' statements can be commented out, or you can use an environment or program variable to turn them on and off -- e.g.

```
say "\$a is $a; \%b is " . Dumper(\%b) if $verbose; ## set a variable 'VERBOSE'
```

If you haven't discovered [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html), it will become your best friend during development: it allows you to inspect the contents of data structures and objects and work out why your carefully-written code isn't working as it should!

Perl testing is too big an issue to cover in an SO answer, but have a look at [Test](http://perldoc.perl.org/Test.html) and [Test::Simple](http://perldoc.perl.org/Test/Simple.html) in the perl docs. Writing a test suite while you write your scripts can save a lot of time--and it's much easier than doing it afterwards!

Comment: @i alarmed alien: wow thanks a lot for all these useful tips! I really appreciate them since i only just started learning perl a few days ago, so any help is just more than welcome to me! i will look up the stuff that you mentioned, I'm sure I will profit highly from it! =)

Comment: @Prawn glad to be of help! :D